# Chrome transition isn't smooth

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So it seems that in IE the transition is smooth without error. But in FireFox and Chrome it blurs a tad bit. Fire Fox not as much.

Here is my example HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="main-table-header">File Name</th>
            <th class="main-table-header">File Size</th>
            <th class="main-table-header">Date Added</th>
            <th class="main-table-header"># Of Versions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<!-- Beginning of dll list. -->
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">DSWINSAT.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">10.KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">04/05/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">4 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">DxEngine32.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">1.03MB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">01/09/2012</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">No Other Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">litezip.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">21.1KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">06/08/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">4 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">rasapi32.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">93.1KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">12/09/2014</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">3 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">ecomwr.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">21.1KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">10/10/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">2 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">mfcuia32.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">43.9KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">08/09/2001</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">No Other Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">icuuc51.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">1.1MB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">06/09/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">1 Version</td>
        </tr>
<!-- End of dll list. -->
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="main-table-header2">File Name</th>
            <th class="main-table-header2">File Size</th>
            <th class="main-table-header2">Date Added</th>
            <th class="main-table-header2"># Of Versions</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Example CSS:

```
.main-table-body {
    text-align:center;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    -moz-transition: all .2s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    display:absolute;
    padding: 2px;
}
.main-table-body:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
```

I looked at a few other posts here at SOF and not much of it was related to the type of code I am using. I placed it in a jsfiddle so you could better understand my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/F8VNN/

Comment: Looks fine on the latest chrome for Mac OSX Mavericks

Comment: On retina display it looks sharp enough. I guess by scaling it you are loosing pixel hinting on your screen. Try to experiment with `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `text-rendering` properties.

Comment: @scrblnrd3 do you have a retina display?

Comment: No I don't have retina